# How do I get a list item by index in elm?

Tags: list, elm

I got a list, and now I want the nth item. In Haskell I would use `!!`, but I can't find an elm variant of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no equivalent of this in Elm.
You could of course implement it yourself.

(Note: This is not a "total" function, so it creates an exception when the index is out of range).

```
infixl 9 !!
(!!) : [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n  = head (drop n xs)
```

A better way would be to define a total function, using the Maybe data type.

```
infixl 9 !!
(!!) : [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
xs !! n  = 
  if | n < 0     -> Nothing
     | otherwise -> case (xs,n) of
         ([],_)    -> Nothing
         (x::xs,0) -> Just x
         (_::xs,n) -> xs !! (n-1)
```

Comment: Just to add another alternative (last (take index list) -> works only if index is not 0 or 1 but you get the idea.

Comment: Haskell raises an out of range exception when you use (!!) out of range. I guess it would make sense to use Maybe but it seems odd to request an element from a list and get something of a type that's not the type of the elements in the list (in this case getting Maybe a instead of a)

Comment: In more recent versions of Elm, you can define `get n xs  = List.head (List.drop n xs)` and it's a total function, done. The `|` syntax above was removed in 0.16.

Answer (score 41):

Elm added arrays in [0.12.1](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.12.1.elm), and the implementation was massively overhauled in 0.19 to improve correctness and performance.

```
import Array

myArray = Array.fromList [1..5]

myItem = Array.get 2 myArray
```

Arrays are zero-indexed. Negative indices are not supported currently (bummer, I know).

Note that `myItem : Maybe Int`. Elm does everything it can to avoid runtime errors, so out of bounds access returns an explicit `Nothing`.

If you find yourself looking to index into a list rather than take the head and tail, you should consider using an array.

[Array documentation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Array)

Comment: `negativeGet index array = get (index + length array) array`

Comment: Does the last line still hold true in light of https://github.com/elm-lang/core/issues/649 ?

Comment: The fixed array implementation has been merged but not released.

Comment: Confirm. Latest release 5.1.1 is from 2017-01-23 https://github.com/elm-lang/core/releases and Skinney commited on 2017-04-02 https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/4213c610b3ecb4b856e09b6b07577d06c0e3dfef#diff-67a364ff7fde87ebc2f09ac1c9ad0680

Comment: You could make this support both positive and negative indices by `mod`ing the index by the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this:

```
(!!): Int -> List a -> Maybe a

(!!) index list =                          -- 3 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

   if  (List.length list) >= index then

        List.take index list               -- [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        |> List.reverse                    -- [ 3, 2, 1 ]
        |> List.head                       -- Just 3
   else 
      Nothing
```

Of course you get a Maybe and you need to unwrap it when you use this function. There is not guarantee that your list will not be empty, or that you ask for a imposible index (like 1000) - so that's why elm compiler forces you to account for that case.

```
main = 
let 
  fifthElement = 
    case 5 !! [1,2,3,4,255,6] of  // not sure how would you use it in Haskell?! But look's nice as infix function. (inspired by @Daniël Heres)
      Just a ->
        a
      Nothing ->
        -1
in
    div [] 
        [ text <| toString fifthElement ]         // 255
```

Comment: @Frederick Nord yes, in 0.19.. custom operators have been taken out.