# How do I add a second die to this elm effects example?

Tags: elm

I am new to Elm and have been looking at the following example (note this is under the newer 0.17 architecture, where Action is now Command):
http://elm-lang.org/examples/random

There is a follow up challenge to add a second die to the example, so that a single click of the button rolls a new value for each die.  My idea is to change the model to hold two separate values, one for each die, ala

```
type alias Model =
       { dieFace1 : Int
       , dieFace2 : Int
       }
```

This works fine until I get to the update block.  I am not sure how to update the Random number generator to create two values.  The function is a bit confusing to me.

```
type Msg
  = Roll
  | NewFace Int Int


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Roll ->
      **(model, Random.generate NewFace (Random.int 1 6))** <-- not sure what to do here

    NewFace newFace1 newFace2 ->
      (Model newFace1 newFace2, Cmd.none)
```

The documentation for the Random.generate function is a bit light -

> generate : (a -> msg) -> Generator a -> Cmd msg
>
> Create a command that will generate random values.

Is this even the correct approach to handle two dice, or is there a better way?  I am an elm noob, please be nice :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Random.int` is a primitive generator that gives you a single random int. You need a generator that gives you exactly two random integers.

Random number generators can be built up from more primitive generators to create more complex generators. Fortunately, Elm has just such a function, [`Random.pair`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Random#pair) which lets you specify which two generators you want for each part of the tuple.

Let's pull the die generator into its own function to avoid repeating ourselves:

```elm
dieGenerator : Random.Generator Int
dieGenerator =
  Random.int 1 6
```

Now we can build another generator that gives us the random value of a pair of die:

```elm
diePairGenerator : Random.Generator (Int, Int)
diePairGenerator =
  Random.pair dieGenerator dieGenerator
```

Since we're dealing with a tuple of ints, let's update your `Msg` definition of `NewFace Int Int` to `NewFaces (Int, Int)`. That will allow your `Roll` handler to be nice and clean:

```elm
Roll ->
  (model, Random.generate NewFaces diePairGenerator)
```

If you want to try moving  beyond this, think about what it would take to allow for any number of die to be rolled. Take this idea of building complex generators from more primitive generators and use the documentation for the [`Random`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Random) module us a guide.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the pointers to the correct part of the documentation, too.  It looks like making n number of die rolls might involve parameterizing a Random.list of Random.ints to contain the number of desired dice, I think. Thanks for the answer and the new homework.

Comment: Thanks Chad for explaining in details. Worked like a charm. I have set up a gist for the lazy: https://gist.github.com/dotcs/3b3626cfbe5b0744134f7af8edcb32c5

Comment: How does the solution look like if we don't expect a tuple of `Int`, but _two_ `Int` parameters? I.e. if `Msg` is defined as `NewFaces Int Int` as intuited by the OP?

Comment: If you have the message `NewFaces2 Int Int`, your `update` handler could look like this: `(model, Random.generate (uncurry NewFaces2) diePairGenerator)`. The function [`uncurry`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Basics#uncurry) will take the tuple parameter and pass the values into `NewFaces2` as two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `batch` like here https://gist.github.com/davidchase/40c27042bccfb00d786af0360b5bc3ea.

Another is to use `Random.pair` or `Random.list` if you need more than 2:

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as Html
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Random


main : Program Never
main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- MODEL

type alias Model =
  { dieFaces : (List Int)
  }

-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199398/how-do-i-get-a-list-item-by-index-in-elm#comment56252508_23201661
get : Int -> List a -> Maybe a
get n xs = List.head (List.drop n xs)

-- http://rundis.github.io/blog/2016/elm_maybe.html
getOrOne : Int -> List Int -> Int
getOrOne n xs = Maybe.withDefault 1 (get n xs)

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model [1, 1], Cmd.none)

-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = Roll
  | NewFace (List Int)

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Roll ->
      (model, Random.generate NewFace (Random.list 2 (Random.int 1 6)))

    NewFace newFace ->
      (Model newFace, Cmd.none)

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ img [ src ("/img/Alea_" ++ toString (getOrOne 0 model.dieFaces) ++ ".png")] []
    , img [ src ("/img/Alea_" ++ toString (getOrOne 1 model.dieFaces) ++ ".png")] []
    , button [ onClick Roll ] [ text "Roll" ]
    ]
```

and another https://github.com/jcollard/random-examples/blob/master/src/Dice.elm

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changes described in the accepted answer by @ChadGilbert, I had to change `NewFaces` update case too (using `elm 0.18.0`).

```
NewFaces newFaces ->
  let
    (newFace1, newFace2) = newFaces
  in
    (Model newFace1 newFace2, Cmd.none)
```